# Ionic Couchbase Lite Karma Jasmine Unit Testing

Tags: ionic-framework, jasmine, karma-jasmine, couchbase-lite

After some struggle, I successfully have jasmine tests running using karma, but I can't seem to find an answer to this question:

#### How can I run my jasmine tests on an actual device to test functions related couchbase lite database?

I am using this: https://github.com/couchbaselabs/ng-couchbase-lite

This is my test:

```
     describe('SetupService tests', function() {
        
        it('SetupService should instantiate', function() { 
            expect(SetupService).toBeDefined();
        }); 
        
        it('it should instantiate database', function() { 
            var database = null; 
            SetupService.setupConfig();
            expect(database).not.toBeNull();
        });  
    });
```

So I need to run the tests on an actual device so the db can successfully be created. I am new to unit testing and currently only using karam cli.

The setup config showing that it requires couchbase lite and cordova:

```
    var setupConfig = function() {
         console.log("set up config");
         var deferred = $q.defer();

         if(!window.cblite) { 
             deferred.reject('Couchbase Lite not installed');  
         } 
         else {
             cblite.getURL(function(err, url) {
                 console.log("cblite get url");
                 if(err) {
                     console.log(err);
                     deferred.reject("There was an error getting the database URL");  
                 }
                 else{
                     database = new $couchbase(url, appDbName);  
                     database.createDatabase().then(function(result) {
                         var views = setupViews();
                         database.createDesignDocument("_design/todo", views);
                         database.listen();
                         deferred.resolve(true); 
                     }, function(error) {
                         // we will not reject this err, as it is caused when a db already exists
                         // so it will happen everytime
                         deferred.resolve(err);  
                     });
                 } 
             }); 
         } 

         return deferred.promise;
     };
```

Comment: Could you not use appium, or selenium to spin up the app on the device and then execute these tests whilst it is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a folder called `tests` in www/

   .
2. Download latest standalone jasmine zip from [Here](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/releases)

   a. Put the `lib` folder in `www/tests`

   b. Copy `SpecRunner.html` to `www/`

.

3. Make your `SpecRunner.html` look exactly like your `index.html`

.

4. Then add jasmine css and scripts to `SpecRunner.html` just before `</head>`

   ```
   <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="tests/lib/jasmine-x.x.x/jasmine_favicon.png">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="tests/lib/jasmine-x.x.x/jasmine.css">
   <style>
       .jasmine_html-reporter{
           width: 100%;
           margin: 200px 0px;
       } 
   </style>
   ```
5. At the end of the `body` tag, add jasmine lib scripts:

   ```
   <script src="tests/lib/jasmine-x.x.x/jasmine.js"></script>
   <script src="tests/lib/jasmine-x.x.x/jasmine-html.js"></script>
   <script src="tests/lib/jasmine-x.x.x/boot.js"></script>
   ```

.

6. Open `boot.js` in `www/tests/lib/jasmine-x.x.x/boot.js`

   Look for the `window.load` function and replace with this:

   ```
     window.onload = function() {
       if (currentWindowOnload) {
         currentWindowOnload();
       }
       jasmine.initialize  = htmlReporter.initialize;
       jasmine.execute     = env.execute;
     };
   ```

.

7. In the ctrl of you starting page, add this when everything has loaded:

   ```
        if(window.jasmine){  
            console.log("---------------------------------------------------------");
            console.log("STARTING JASMINE...");  
            jasmine.initialize();
            jasmine.execute(); 
            console.log("---------------------------------------------------------");
            console.log("JASMINE INITIALED");
            console.log("---------------------------------------------------------");
        }
   ```

   I personally bootstrap angular manually, so I start jasmine after angular is bootstrapped and my main Ctrl is loaded:

   ```
   window.ionic.Platform.ready(function() {
       console.log("device ready");  
       angular.element(document).ready(function() {
           angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']); 
       }); 
   });
   ```

   Then in my Ctrl after I've loaded a document from Couchbase, I start jasmine.

.

8. Finally to Run Tests:

   rename `index.html` to `index_backup.html`
   rename `SpecRunner.html` to `index.html`

   and run `ionic run android --device`

.

9. Automate Step 8 using Makefile:

   ```
   set-test: 
       @if [ -f "www/SpecRunner.html" ]; \
       then \
           mv www/index.html www/index_backup.html; \
           mv www/SpecRunner.html www/index.html; \
       else \
           echo "test already set"; \
       fi

   unset-test:
       @if [ -f "www/SpecRunner.html" ]; \
       then \
           echo "test already unset"; \
       else \
           mv www/index.html www/SpecRunner.html;  \
           mv www/index_backup.html www/index.html; \
       fi       
   test:  
       make set-test    
       ionic run android --device
   ```
10. Sample Test

    ```
    describe('AccountsCtrl', function() { 

        var $scope;
        var app; 
        var $ionicSideMenu;
        var helper;

        var params = {
            name : 'Test Person',
            id: '112654'
        };


        beforeAll(function(done){  
            app = AppService;
            helper = getService("ActivitiesHelper");  
            $state.go('app.activities',params);  

        // wait for the state to change
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                $scope = getScope("activities"); 
                done();
            },1000) 

        });


        it('expects $scope.app to be defined', function() { 
            expect($scope.app).toBeDefined();
        });     


    });
    ```